# What does (width: w, height: h) iterate over in Bootstrap scss _sizing file?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I am trying to understand bootstrap utilities/_sizing.scss file and I don't understand the first for loop in side there.  Where are the width & height values coming from?[image: Highlighted Loop]

Comment: literally `w` and `h`, resulting on w-100, h-100, w-50, h-50, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On bootstrap scss folder you can find $sizes values declared in _variable.scss file.

```
// This variable affects the `.h-*` and `.w-*` classes.
$sizes: () !default;
$sizes: map-merge(
  (
    25: 25%,
    50: 50%,
    75: 75%,
    100: 100%,
    auto: auto
  ),
  $sizes
);
```

Here the loop explanation:

```
@each $prop, $abbrev in (width: w, height: h) {
  @each $size, $length in $sizes {
    .#{$abbrev}-#{$size} { #{$prop}: $length !important; }
  }
}
```

In the first each width and height are the $prop, w and h are the $abbrev.
The second each loop iterate $size and $length that come from _variables.scss file.

$size values are (25,50,75,100,auto)
$length values are (25%,50%,75%,100%,auto)

The result is that it generate all the combination of classes for width and height with that size and length like this one:

```
.w-100{ //where w is the $abbrev and 100 is the $size
    width:100%; //where width is the $prop and 100% is the $length
}
```

Then as you obviously know you can apply those classes to your html like this:

```
<div class="w-100"></div> <!-- A 100% width div -->
```